# Multi filter select on dataTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm currently using jquery datatables plugin. I want to use "datatables multi filter select" on it and use the tabletools. The tabletools works fine, but the "datatables multi filter select" not working. The table not showing the drop down filter on the footer of the columns.

Js code

```
var oTable=$('#table').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0, 1, 9]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": base_url + "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    {
                        "sExtends": "csv",
                        "sFileName": "Report_"+date+".csv",
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                        "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' }
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "xls",
                        "sFileName": "Report_"+date+".xlsx",
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                        "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' }
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "sFileName": "Report_"+date+".pdf",
                        "sPdfMessage": "Summary Info",
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                        "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' }
                    },
                    "print"
            ]
        }
    });
```

What's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `tfoot` element? This code requires footer to be present in HTML markup?